# Why does GetLogPen fail with a custom pen?

Tags: windows, mfc, gdi

The calls to `GetLogPen()` and `GetExtLogPen()` both fail. They return zero...

```
CBrush Brush;
Brush.CreateSolidBrush( COLOR_MINORSELECTION );
Brush.GetLogBrush( &lBrush );
DWORD Style[] = { 3, 1 };
CPen CustomPen;
CustomPen.CreatePen( PS_USERSTYLE, 1, &lBrush, 2, Style );
CPen *pOldPen = pDC->SelectObject( &CustomPen );
LOGPEN LogPen;
if( CustomPen->GetLogPen( &LogPen ) == 0 )
{
    EXTLOGPEN ExtLogPen;
    if( CustomPen->GetExtLogPen( &ExtLogPen ) == 0 )
        return;
}
```

The failure appears to be because of the `PS_USERSTYLE` being used for the pen style. If I do this with a `PS_SOLID` pen, I get the `LogPen` structure filled in as I expect.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the [CPen::GetExtLogPen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht90xyhw.aspx) implementation:

> ```
> int CPen::GetExtLogPen(EXTLOGPEN* pLogPen) {
>     return ::GetObject(m_hObject, sizeof(EXTLOGPEN), pLogPen);
> }
> ```

The implementation ignores the trailing variable-sized array of `DWORD`s in the [EXTLOGPEN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162711) structure. This structure is defined as:

> ```
> typedef struct tagEXTLOGPEN {
>     DWORD     elpPenStyle;
>     DWORD     elpWidth;
>     UINT      elpBrushStyle;
>     COLORREF  elpColor;
>     ULONG_PTR elpHatch;
>     DWORD     elpNumEntries;
>     DWORD     elpStyleEntry[1];
> } EXTLOGPEN, *PEXTLOGPEN;
> ```

The call to `CPen::GetExtLogPen` succeeds, if the *elpStyleEntry* array is at most one element long. This is true for all pens except for those pens that have the `PS_USERSTYLE` pen style. When using the `PS_USERSTYLE` pen style, the *elpStyleEntry* entry will have at least 2 entries.

The workaround in the case of pens with the `PS_USERSTYLE` pen style is to use the Windows API [GetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904) call, and circumvent the MFC implementation:

```cpp
// Query for required buffer size
int sizeRequired = ::GetObject(CustomPen.m_hObject, 0, nullptr);
// Allocate buffer (may not be properly aligned)
std::vector<byte> buffer(sizeRequired);
// Retrieve the entire EXTLOGPEN structure
int ret = ::GetObject(CustomPen.m_hObject, static_cast<int>(buffer.size()), buffer.data());
assert(ret == static_cast<int>(buffer.size());
// Cast to const ref for convenient access
const EXTLOGPEN& elp = *reinterpret_cast<const EXTLOGPEN*>(buffer.data());
```

Unfortunately, the [solution posted by Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37382103/1889329) doesn't solve the issue, because the `CPen::GetExtLogPen` passes `sizeof(EXTLOGPEN)` to the `GetObject` call, not the true size of its argument.

---

*Note: A [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2741367) has been submitted to Microsoft Connect.*

Answer (score 0):

The `EXTLOGPEN` structure defines space for only one style parameter, but allows up to 16. It is unclear how `GetExtLogPen` determines how much space is available. Try this and see if it helps.

```
struct EXTLOGPEN16 : public EXTLOGPEN
{
    DWORD elpStyleMore[15];

public:
    EXTLOGPEN16()
    {
        elpNumEntries = 16;
    }
};

EXTLOGPEN16 ExtLogPen;
if (CustomPen->GetExtLogPen(&ExtLogPen) == 0)
    // ...
```

Comment: This suggestion reminds me of data structures that have a size value as the first entry. I tried this but had no luck. I also tried it using a single value for the style array and it worked! Apparently, the MS programmers who wrote the code for this decided that no one needed the function to work if they had a more complicated dash/dot/gap style for their lines.

Comment: `GetExtLogPen` presumably calls [GetObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd144904). `GetObject` returns the number of bytes copied to the return buffer. This value implicitly tells you the number of used values. @DavidRector: This a very common pattern used in variable-sized structures. The trailing one-sized array is necessary for the compiler to produce correct alignment. This solves a different problem from the one you were talking about; structures carrying an explicit size field as their first entry are useful to implement versioning.

Comment: @IInspectable, I'm familiar with that variable-sized structure pattern from older Windows code that I've written. `GetExtLogPen` does not accept a structure size value and can therefore only return data if there is zero or one entry in the style array. I realize now that I can call `GetObject` myself and I suspect that it will work as desired. If you post the `GetObject` suggestion as an answer, I'll try it and then mark it as the answer since it is obvious now that `GetExtLogPen` cannot handle more than one style element in the structure.

Comment: Why do you say that it allows up to 16? Looking at the documentation, I don't see any upper bound on the length, aside from the fact that the number of entries must fit in a `DWORD` (so it can fit in `elpNumEntries`). I ask not to be pedantic, but because I just wrote a retrieval function in a wrapper class, and had to use dynamic allocation and a smart pointer, which I'd rather not do if I can be sure that there will never be more than 16 entries and can use your approach instead.

Comment: @CodyGray if you look at the `dwStyleCount` parameter of [`ExtCreatePen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162705(v=vs.85).aspx) you'll see that it's limited to 16.

Comment: Hmm, so it does. Thanks for bringing that to my attention! Very strange that it doesn't mention it in the actual documentation for the structure.